# Codeigniter Facebook Config File not loading

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have this code to start using Facebook SDK V4 with Codeigniter. This is the Facebook.php file inside Library Folder next to Facebook SDK folder files:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
  session_start();
}

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/Facebook');
require_once("autoload.php");

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' ); 

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl; 

class Facebook {
  var $ci;
  var $helper;
  var $session;
  var $permissions;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');

    echo $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook');

exit;
```

I am having some errors and found that the problem was the config variables are not loading.

My config file is like this:

```
<?php
$config['facebook']['api_id'] = 'api-id-key';
$config['facebook']['app_secret'] = 'app-secret-key';
$config['facebook']['redirect_url'] = 'http://neuronr.com/facebook/redirect';
$config['facebook']['permissions'] = array(
  'email',
  'user_location',
  'user_birthday'
);
```

What am I doing wrong with the config files? I've read documentation and all seems correct to me.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Your code as shown makes no sense, your class definition for `Facebook` is not even finished.

Comment: You are right. I've just pasted the part I need to show the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Now my code worked. Just one line added:

```
$this->ci->load->config('facebook'); // this is the line that I added
```

Thanks for the inspiration :)

Comment: where to add, this line? let me try in autoload.